# How to test a method with a parameter using RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec3

I have the following RSpec:

```
describe Job do
  let(:job) { Job.new }

  describe 'run_job' do
    context 'success' do
        my_param = [{"job1" => "run"}, {"job2" => "run again"}]

        it 'should pass' do
            test_result = job.run_job(my_param)
            expect(test_result[0]["job1"]).to eq("run")
        end
     end
  end
end
```

The method:

```
Class Job
  def run_job(my_param)
    # puts "#{my_param}"
    my_param.each do|f|
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

when I run the test I receive the following error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I print out `my_param` in the console and see same object that was passed to the test, `[{"job1" => "run"}, {"job2" => "run again"}]`. I have no idea why `my_param` is `nil` when calling `.each`. What did I do wrong? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: _"I have no idea why my_param is nil"_ – local variables defined outside the example are not available within the example. Just like a local variable defined outside a method is not available within the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_param` should be defined inside the `it` block or you should use `let` to define `my_param`

***Inside it block***

```
describe Job do
  let(:job) { Job.new }

  describe 'run_job' do
    context 'success' do        
        it 'should pass' do
            my_param = [{"job1" => "run"}, {"job2" => "run again"}]

            test_result = job.run_job(my_param)
            expect(test_result[0]["job1"]).to eq("run")
        end
     end
  end
end
```

***Using let***

```
describe Job do
  let(:job) { Job.new }

  describe 'run_job' do
    context 'success' do
        let(:my_param) { [{"job1" => "run"}, {"job2" => "run again"}] }


        it 'should pass' do
            test_result = job.run_job(my_param)
            expect(test_result[0]["job1"]).to eq("run")
        end
     end
  end
end
```

***Using before block***

```
describe Job do
  let(:job) { Job.new }

  describe 'run_job' do
    context 'success' do
        before(:all) do
          @my_param = [{"job1" => "run"}, {"job2" => "run again"}]
        end

        it 'should pass' do
            test_result = job.run_job(@my_param)
            expect(test_result[0]["job1"]).to eq("run")
        end
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can I use `let` to call `job.run_job(my_param)` right under context? If so, what would the syntax be?

Comment: Yes @CiCi Check `Using let` section in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be defining in the before block and forming it the instance variable as;

```
before { @my_param = [{"job1" => "run"}, {"job2" => "run again"}] }
```

or

but the best way would be to use let:

```
describe Job do
  let(:job) { Job.new }
  let(:my_param) { [{"job1" => "run"}, {"job2" => "run again"}] }
  describe 'run_job' do
    context 'success' do

      it 'should pass' do
        test_result = job.run_job(my_param)
        expect(test_result[0]["job1"]).to eq("run")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesnt make any sense defining `my_param` inside the method, as there will be no use of parameter which passed to method and defined variable will be `static` instead of `dynamic`.

Comment: Here my_param was to be used only once. so according to me it can be used like this.

Answer (score 0):

[Better Specs](http://www.betterspecs.org/#let) recommends using `let` to assign variables:

```
describe Job do
  let(:job) { Job.new }

  describe 'run_job' do
    context 'success' do
      let(:my_param) { [{"job1" => "run"}, {"job2" => "run again"}] }

      it 'should pass' do
        test_result = job.run_job(my_param)
        expect(test_result[0]["job1"]).to eq("run")
      end
    end
  end
end
```